# Multidimensional array to indented list

Tags: java, eclipse, multidimensional-array, indentation

I had the task to write a method which recursively prints out the content of an example array. And I managed to that and technically finished it.

But I was wondering if it is possible to print the code more "pretty"?

```java
public class multirecursion {
    static String[][][] example = {
        {
            {"1", "2", "3", "4"},
            {"A", "B", "C"},
            {"5", "6", "7", "8"}
        },
        {
            {"01", "02", "03", "04"},
            {"11", "12", "14"}
        }
    };

    static void printRecursive(Object[] objs) {
        for (Object obj : objs) {
            if (obj.getClass().isArray()) {
                printRecursive((Object[]) obj);
            } else {
                System.out.println(obj.toString().trim());
            }
        }
    }

    static void printIndented(Object[] objs, String indent) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printRecursive(example);
    }
}
```

I know that I probably need another parameter for my printIndented method, but I don't know how to go from there. I'm grateful for any advice.

Okay I solved it. Here's the rest for anyone interested:

```java
static void printInXml(Object[] objs, String indent) {
    for (Object obj : objs) {
        if (obj.getClass().isArray()) {
            System.out.println(indent + "<container>");
            printInXml((Object[]) obj, indent + "   ");
            System.out.println(indent + "</container>");
        } else {
            System.out.println(indent + "<string>"
                    + obj.toString().trim() + "</string>");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printInXml(example, "");
}
```

And that's how it looks like:

```xml
<container>
    <container>
        <string>1</string>
        <string>2</string>
        <string>3</string>
        <string>4</string>
    </container>
    <container>
        <string>A</string>
        <string>B</string>
        <string>C</string>
    </container>
    <container>
        <string>5</string>
        <string>6</string>
        <string>7</string>
        <string>8</string>
    </container>
</container>
<container>
    <container>
        <string>01</string>
        <string>02</string>
        <string>03</string>
        <string>04</string>
    </container>
    <container>
        <string>11</string>
        <string>12</string>
        <string>14</string>
    </container>
</container>
```

Comment: [edit] your question and post how you want the output to look.

Comment: In Eclipse the command to format the default code is through ´CTRL + SHIFT + F´. But your code contains many errors like not finalizing class and function and also the excess of commas will cause problems in compiling and formatting the code.

Comment: I didn't realize it cut the last lines off. Thank you!

Comment: Rather than edit your question and incorporate the answer into it, you should answer your own question. Refer to [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). And by the way, if you would have mentioned in your initial question that you want the output as an XML string, that would have provided me (and I'm sure a lot of other people) enough information in order to provide you with a relevant answer. Refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Since you told this is an assignment I won't go as far as solve it for you, I'll just give you an advice `printIndentedRecursive(Object[] objs, String indent,Integer RecursionLevel)`.

From here should be pretty obvious.

Comment: It's not really obvious for me. I undestand the need for the second parameter indent (which I mentioned before), but not for the third one.

Comment: The third one is needed to know how much you want to indent that portion depending on how deep is the nesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can process this array as follows:

```java
String[][][] arr3d = {
        {{"1", "2", "3", "4"},
                {"A", "B", "C"},
                {"5", "6", "7", "8"}},
        {{"01", "02", "03", "04"},
                {"11", "12", "14"}}};
```

```java
String result = Arrays.stream(arr3d)
        .map(arr2d -> Arrays.stream(arr2d)
                .map(arr1d -> Arrays.stream(arr1d)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(
                                "</string>\n\t\t<string>",
                                "\t\t<string>",
                                "</string>")))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(
                        "\n\t</container>\n\t<container>\n",
                        "\t<container>\n",
                        "\n\t</container>")))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(
                "\n</container>\n<container>\n",
                "<container>\n",
                "\n</container>"));
```

```java
// output
System.out.println(result);
```

```xml
<container>
    <container>
        <string>1</string>
        <string>2</string>
        <string>3</string>
        <string>4</string>
    </container>
    <container>
        <string>A</string>
        <string>B</string>
        <string>C</string>
    </container>
    <container>
        <string>5</string>
        <string>6</string>
        <string>7</string>
        <string>8</string>
    </container>
</container>
<container>
    <container>
        <string>01</string>
        <string>02</string>
        <string>03</string>
        <string>04</string>
    </container>
    <container>
        <string>11</string>
        <string>12</string>
        <string>14</string>
    </container>
</container>
```